# Can't change Screen Brightness | Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 AMD Ryzen 7 4800H Series

Tags: 22.04

Can't change Screen Brightness

```
engin@engin-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05:~$ ls /sys/class/backlight/
amdgpu_bl1  ideapad
```

---

```
uname -r 
5.15.0-41-generic
```

### Grub

```
    # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.backlight=0"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Why did you add `amdgpu.backlight=0`?

Comment: https://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=63600.0;topicseen

Comment: Do NOT post answers or edit your post *just* to bump it.  This is not a forum, and bumping posts is forbidden.